# :prompt appearing in collection_select when a records value is expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry, this may seem like a simple issue, but: I have a collection_select element that is called via ajax from a _updateregions.html.erb file for creating and editing records that looks like:

```
<%= collection_select(:wine, :wineregionid,  regions,  :wineregionid, :regionname,
                    options = {:selected => :wineregionid, :prompt   => "Select a Region"}
 ) %>
```

The problem is, when editing an existing record, the prompt is appearing by default instead on the records value. When I remove the :prompt, it works fine... question is, how can I make this work for both the New and Edit case?
According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html I think I'm doing it right....

> collection_select(object, method,
>   collection, value_method, text_method,
>   options = {}, html_options = {})
>
> Returns  and  tags for
>   the collection of existing return
>   values of method for object‘s class.
>   The value returned from calling method
>   on the instance object will be
>   selected. If calling method returns
>   nil, no selection is made without
>   including :prompt or :include_blank in
>   the options hash.

Answer (score 0):

i think :prompt donot takes a string .
it should be true/false or null.
try this

```
    <%= collection_select(:wine, :wineregionid,  regions,  :wineregionid, :regionname,
                options = {:selected => :wineregionid, :prompt   => true) %>
```

Comment: tried that as well :prompt does take strings - setting prompt to true simply sets a generic prompt.